# Unity 2D A* Pathfinding: Gameobject of Grids position problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid, position, path-finding, gameobject

In my project i used A* Pathfinding system from Sebastian Lague tutorial. It's looks same [like this.](https://github.com/SebLague/Pathfinding-2D/tree/master/Scripts) 
I did some small changes. I have a problem with one thing. I have an game object with Grid script which divide area on small pieces and i want to change this game object position (when player went to far), because I have too big map to contain all grids on start. But when i did it, pathfinding script doesn't work on new grid position just on old. I don't know why. Can you help me?

Comment: The grid should never need to move, the grid is a simple 2 dimensional matrix with cost information (in this example the cost is only ever 1 or not walkable). What size of grid are you trying to create? The problem you're going to have is if you move the grid, you're going to have to take this offset into account everywhere else, since grid pos [0,0] relates to Unity pos [0, 0, 0].

Comment: My map is random generated rooms, some like Bliding of Issac, each room have size 35 x 19 and distance between them is 20. I use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KY4I5lMwf5I&t=4s) room generator, and i need small grid pieces: 0,2f. Its too much for this when map size is 500 x 500. The easiest way is set grid size to 35 x 19 and change it position when player move to another room and here is the problem. I know i need offset but i don't know when i need to add it, and how it should look...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i solve it. Just added trasfrom.position to percentX and percentY in NodeFromWorldPoint function.